Zod schema to allow one of the properties in an object
I have an object which has a mandatory name property, and contains nickname or other proprety. This is how my schema looks like,
export const studentSchema = z
  .object({
    name: z.string().min(1).max(20)
  })
  .and(
    z
      .object({
        nickname: z.string().min(1).max(20)
      })
      .or(
        z.object({
          other: z.string().min(1).max(14)
        })
      )
  )

The problem is, the validation passed when both nickname and other are passed
{
  name: "John",
  nickname: "any",
  other: "play"
}

How can I fix the schema so that it only allow one of the properties in the object? For example,
{
  name: "John",
  nickname: "any"
}

or
{
  name: "John",
  other: "play"
}


Normally, you'd use .strict() but it works only with ZodObject. .and convert the object to intersection.

Update your schema as below:
export const studentSchema = z
  .object({
    name: z.string().min(1).max(20),
    nickname: z.string().min(1).max(20),
  })
  .or(
    z.object({
      name: z.string().min(1).max(20),
      other: z.string().min(1).max(14),
    }),
  );


The problem is solved by defining the schemas like this,
const baseSchema = z.object({ name: z.string().min(1).max(20) })

const studentSchema = z.union([
  baseSchema.extend({ nickname: z.string().min(1).max(20) }).strict(),
  baseSchema.extend({ other: z.string().min(1).max(20) }).strict()
])

const s = z.array(invoiceSchema).nonempty()

studentSchema.parse({
  name: 'John',
  nickname: 'any'
})

studentSchema.parse({
  name: 'John',
  other: 'play'
})

let result = studentSchema.safeParse({
  name: 'John'
}).success

result || console.log('Failed when both `nickname` and `other` are missing')

result = studentSchema.safeParse({
  name: 'John',
  nickname: 'any',
  other: 'play'
}).success

result || console.log('Failed when both `nickname` and `other` are specified')

Please let me know if you have a more elegant solution!
